# Wordpress redirect the page if a user login is empty

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, authentication

I managed to make the redirect work with this function

```
add_action( 'wp_authenticate', '_catch_empty_user', 1, 2 );

function _catch_empty_user( $username, $pwd ) {
 if ( empty( $username ) ) {
   wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_to_whereever_you_want );
   exit();
 }
}
```

But when I go to the page www.mysite.com/wp-login.php, it still redirects no matter what.

Is it possible to make the wp-login.php page work as usual and only redirect when the actual login process is wrong or empty?

Thanks

Comment: Use the global $pagenow to check if you on the login page, then simply return null.

Comment: Try using this: http://projectivemotion.com/blog/2011/12/16/redirect-failed-login-attempt-wordpress/

Comment: Thanks @TomChew-headMillard, I have tried with this 
`add_action( 'wp_authenticate', '_catch_empty_user', 1, 2 );

function _catch_empty_user( $username, $pwd ) {
    $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    if ( !in_array( $GLOBALS['pagenow'], array( 'wp-login.php', 'wp-register.php' ) ) && (empty( $username ) || empty( $pwd )) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( $referrer . '/members' );
        exit();
    }
}`
but it didn't work

Comment: Thanks @ManojKumar, I have added that code and changed it accordingly but it also didn't work